# Style recursive css for angular template and container

Tags: css, angular, recursion, tree

I have my HTML in a tree recursive call to display a tree hierarchy. I can't figure it out how to style css inside ng-container that does the recursive call.

```
<ul>
  <ng-template #recursiveList let-list>
   <li *ngFor="let item of list" [selected]="isSelected">
     <span> {{item.title}} </span>
    <ul *ngIf="item.children.length > 0">
       <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.children }"></ng-container>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: list }"></ng-container>
</ul>
```

CSS:

> ul > li { 
>         list-style: none;
>         &.selected { color: red; }
>   span { font-size: 16px; color: green; } }

Comment: What element do you need to style and how?

Comment: It would be easier when you would use a component instead of `ngTemplateOutlet`, then you could add the styles to the component and control it by values you pass to `@Input()`s.

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten I updated the CSS I am trying to style.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer when I use another component and pass in value by using @Input(), I can't style the selected element.

Comment: Why can't you style the component then?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `class.selected` syntax as described in the [Binding targets](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets) topic to apply a CSS class binding. Then, I believe that a list item has the `isSelected` property. It's not global. So, the code should be:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items" [class.selected]="item.isSelected">
  <span>{{item.title}}</span>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="List; context:{ $implicit: item.children }"></ng-container>
</li>
```

See the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gEhlCPtsMxI11Y3Ngmrg?p=preview) that illustrates this.